# Workflow Exception - Retry handling - Adobe AEM/CQ

Tags: aem

Workflow Processes throw `WorkflowException` in case of failure, there is a setting in Web Console `Apache Sling Job Default Queue`. In this max retries is set to 10 on failure.

Now on failure, workflow is retried 10 more times on failure. So if a workflow if having step for example Version Creation, 10 more versions are created of resource.

I could think of following solutions

1. Set the max retries count on failure to 0 in `Apache Sling Job Default Queue`. Is it fine to do this?
2. Replace OOTB Version Creation process with custom process and add check for retries probably by saving flag in workflow metadata.

Version Creation process is taken as example here, it could be any other process which is doing some other functionality, that would also be tried 10 more times on failure. Has anyone faced similar situation?

Answer (score 2):

It is not advisable to make it zero. Some workflow needs to be retried, for example activation workflow, when there were network issues or publish boxes were down etc. Your settings would totally bypass this safety mechanism.

I would prefer your second method as an alternative. `org.apache.sling.event.jobs.Jobs` has `getRetryCount()`.

Comment: Thank you Dileepa for response. Isn't it like, if we make retry to 0, then on failure workflow would be shown in failed state on first failure itself and it will not retry the workflow. By retired, you mean failure or purging? For the network or publish box is down (replication agent ON/Active), AEM would put request into queue and workflow would complete, as replication is asynchronous. Seems like replication queue is different than workflow job queue

Comment: You are absolutely right about replication queue. Probably I missed that part. But we have workflows which connect to DB, hence would fail , if in future your environment also does these same. Also, does the replication queue usees the same job queues?

Comment: Replication queue is different it seems, there is a separate configuration for replication and workflow queues in OSGi confMgr. In case of failure while connecting to DB (it would throw exception, if we are not suppressing it), the workflow would go to failed state, would not complete. In this case it would show as failed workflow in workflow console. Valid use might be we we want to retry to connect DB (assuming failure due to network or something like that), in that case as you pointed out it would be not advisable to make it zero.

Comment: There is one more configuration, if we want isolate the queue configurations for workflow. We can create a [custom queue](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/deploy/configuring/performance.html#Configure%20the%20Queue%20for%20a%20Specific%20Workflow) to avoid changing the common configuration which would change queue settings for all workflows